# How to introspect field for which getter and setter have different types?

Tags: java, javabeans

I have JAXB-generated Java Beans class which I do not want to change by hand:

```
public class Bar
{
  protected Boolean foo;

  public Boolean getFoo() {
     return this.foo;
  }

  public void setFoo(final boolean value) {
     this.foo = value;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to investigate this class (I need getter and setter) in this way:

```
  PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptiors =
        Introspector.getBeanInfo(Bar.class, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
  for (PropertyDescriptor descriptor : propertyDescriptiors)
  {
     System.out.println("read method: " + descriptor.getReadMethod());
     System.out.println("write method: " + descriptor.getWriteMethod());
  }
```

but it doesn't find setter.

If I change `getFoo` to return primitive `boolean` or `setFoo` to receive `Boolean` object, it works fine.

What can I do to get both getter and setter method from this class without changing their types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, inspector can't find setter because `foo` type is `Boolean`, not `boolean`.

You could use a wrapper

```
public class BarWrapper {
    private Bar bar;

    public Boolean getFoo() {
        return this.bar.getFoo();
    }

    public void setFoo(final Boolean value) {
        this.bar.setFoo(value);
    }
}
```

and then inspect on the wrapper

```
Introspector.getBeanInfo(BarWrapper.class, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors();
```

Comment: I thought about it, but it seems pretty unelegant. Problem is independent form foo type - if it is boolean, result doesn't change. It's more about method parameters/return value consistency. Also that's interesting that if I comment out first method (here getter), it finds setter without any problem.
"You can't" - can you point me to some documentation which tells specifically this? I guess that this behavior is intentional, I'm curious about reasons.

Comment: I searched the documentation into the code. Into the Instrospector's "getTargetPropertyInfo" method, in the try block at row 507(jdk1.8), it's build a PropertyDescriptor for every getter and setter. Each one is featured by its return/parameter type. Then all the PropertyDescriptors are merged into Introspector's "processPropertyDescriptors" method where, as specified into the code "First pass. Find the latest getter method" and "Second pass. Find the latest setter method which has the same type as the getter method".

Comment: Because of this (and because boolean primitive and Boolean class are different types) setter method is not found

Comment: Brilliant. That explains everything. Thanks for your effort!